# Jekyll: activated terminal-table 2.0.0, but your Gemfile requires terminal-table 1.8.0. and warning: already initialized constant URI::REGEXP

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, exec, bundle

When I run `jekyll build --trace` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    10: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
     9: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
     8: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
     6: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.7/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `setup'
     5: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `setup'
     4: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `map'
     3: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:149:in `each'
     2: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:149:in `each'
     1: from /home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:302:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated terminal-table 2.0.0, but your Gemfile requires terminal-table 1.8.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

In this case is not build.

And when I run `bundle exec jekyll build --trace` I get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant URI::VERSION_CODE
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION_CODE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant URI::VERSION
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/version.rb:4: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::ALPHA
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:28: warning: previous definition of ALPHA was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:31: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::ALNUM
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:30: warning: previous definition of ALNUM was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:35: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::HEX
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:34: warning: previous definition of HEX was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:37: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::ESCAPED
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:36: warning: previous definition of ESCAPED was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::UNRESERVED
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:40: warning: previous definition of UNRESERVED was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:46: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::RESERVED
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:45: warning: previous definition of RESERVED was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::DOMLABEL
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:48: warning: previous definition of DOMLABEL was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::TOPLABEL
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:50: warning: previous definition of TOPLABEL was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC2396_REGEXP::PATTERN::HOSTNAME
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:52: warning: previous definition of HOSTNAME was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC3986_Parser::RFC3986_URI
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:6: warning: previous definition of RFC3986_URI was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC3986_Parser::RFC3986_relative_ref
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:7: warning: previous definition of RFC3986_relative_ref was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant URI::REGEXP
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:16: warning: previous definition of REGEXP was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:18: warning: already initialized constant URI::Parser
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:17: warning: previous definition of Parser was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant URI::RFC3986_PARSER
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:18: warning: previous definition of RFC3986_PARSER was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:22: warning: already initialized constant URI::DEFAULT_PARSER
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:21: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PARSER was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::ABS_URI
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of ABS_URI was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::REL_URI
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of REL_URI was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::URI_REF
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of URI_REF was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::ABS_URI_REF
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of ABS_URI_REF was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::REL_URI_REF
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of REL_URI_REF was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::ESCAPED
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of ESCAPED was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::UNSAFE
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of UNSAFE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::SCHEME
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of SCHEME was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::USERINFO
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of USERINFO was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::HOST
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of HOST was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::OPAQUE
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of OPAQUE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::REGISTRY
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of REGISTRY was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::ABS_PATH
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of ABS_PATH was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::REL_PATH
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of REL_PATH was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::QUERY
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of QUERY was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant URI::FRAGMENT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:28: warning: previous definition of FRAGMENT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:340: warning: already initialized constant URI::TBLENCWWWCOMP_
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:277: warning: previous definition of TBLENCWWWCOMP_ was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:346: warning: already initialized constant URI::TBLDECWWWCOMP_
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:283: warning: previous definition of TBLDECWWWCOMP_ was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/common.rb:512: warning: already initialized constant URI::WEB_ENCODINGS_
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/common.rb:449: warning: previous definition of WEB_ENCODINGS_ was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/generic.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant URI::Generic::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/generic.rb:27: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/generic.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant URI::Generic::COMPONENT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/generic.rb:46: warning: previous definition of COMPONENT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/generic.rb:62: warning: already initialized constant URI::Generic::USE_REGISTRY
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/generic.rb:61: warning: previous definition of USE_REGISTRY was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/file.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant URI::File::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/file.rb:12: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/file.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant URI::File::COMPONENT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/file.rb:17: warning: previous definition of COMPONENT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ftp.rb:25: warning: already initialized constant URI::FTP::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ftp.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ftp.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant URI::FTP::COMPONENT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ftp.rb:29: warning: previous definition of COMPONENT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ftp.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant URI::FTP::TYPECODE
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ftp.rb:42: warning: previous definition of TYPECODE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ftp.rb:46: warning: already initialized constant URI::FTP::TYPECODE_PREFIX
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ftp.rb:45: warning: previous definition of TYPECODE_PREFIX was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/http.rb:25: warning: already initialized constant URI::HTTP::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/http.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/http.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant URI::HTTP::COMPONENT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/http.rb:27: warning: previous definition of COMPONENT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/https.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant URI::HTTPS::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/https.rb:19: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ldap.rb:27: warning: already initialized constant URI::LDAP::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ldap.rb:26: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ldap.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant URI::LDAP::COMPONENT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ldap.rb:29: warning: previous definition of COMPONENT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ldap.rb:48: warning: already initialized constant URI::LDAP::SCOPE_ONE
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ldap.rb:47: warning: previous definition of SCOPE_ONE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ldap.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant URI::LDAP::SCOPE_SUB
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ldap.rb:48: warning: previous definition of SCOPE_SUB was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ldap.rb:50: warning: already initialized constant URI::LDAP::SCOPE_BASE
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ldap.rb:49: warning: previous definition of SCOPE_BASE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ldap.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant URI::LDAP::SCOPE
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ldap.rb:46: warning: previous definition of SCOPE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/ldaps.rb:18: warning: already initialized constant URI::LDAPS::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/ldaps.rb:18: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/mailto.rb:22: warning: already initialized constant URI::MailTo::DEFAULT_PORT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/mailto.rb:21: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PORT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/mailto.rb:25: warning: already initialized constant URI::MailTo::COMPONENT
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/mailto.rb:24: warning: previous definition of COMPONENT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/mailto.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant URI::MailTo::HEADER_REGEXP
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/mailto.rb:52: warning: previous definition of HEADER_REGEXP was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/mailto.rb:56: warning: already initialized constant URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
/home/john/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/mailto.rb:55: warning: previous definition of EMAIL_REGEXP was here
Configuration file: /home/john/Projects/lyricall/_config.yml
            Source: /home/john/Projects/lyricall
       Destination: /home/john/Projects/lyricall/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.083 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

but this time site is build.

How can I make jekyll run and get rid of bundle exec errors ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

I had this error during development `You have already activated terminal-table 2.0.0, but your Gemfile requires terminal-table 1.8.0. Prepending bundle exec to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)`

All I had to do is,

`bundle exec jekyll serve`

This solved it.